# What kind of query optimization can be done on this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm listing out orders data based on this query. This query basically pulls the recurring orders data from the table. I'm also using some dropdown and a input field to search / filter query results.

```
SELECT
    orders.id,
    parent_id,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        orders o
    WHERE
        o.parent_id = orders.id
) AS recurring_order_count,
shopify_order_type,
shopify_order_id,
shopify_order_customer_ID,
coupon_code AS coupon,
FORMAT(shopify_order_total_price, 2) AS shopify_order_total_price,
FORMAT(
    shopify_order_subtotal_price,
    2
) AS shopify_order_subtotal_price,
FORMAT(
    shopify_order_total_line_items_price,
    2
) AS shopify_order_total_line_items_price,
FORMAT(commission_amount, 2) AS commission_amount,
(
    CASE WHEN is_paid = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN is_paid = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'Rejected'
END
) AS is_paid,
(
    CASE WHEN is_invoice_generated = 1 THEN 'Pending' ELSE 'Invoice Generated'
END
) AS is_invoice_generated,
DATE_FORMAT(
    shopify_order_created_at,
    '%m-%d-%Y'
) AS shopify_order_created_at,
(
    CASE WHEN is_paused = 0 THEN 'Running' ELSE 'Paused'
END
) AS is_paused,
DATE_FORMAT(
    shopify_recurring_date,
    '%m-%d-%Y'
) AS shopify_recurring_date
FROM
    `orders`
WHERE
    coupon_code LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR shopify_order_id LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR(
        CASE WHEN is_paid = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN is_paid = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'Rejected'
    END
) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR(
    CASE WHEN is_invoice_generated = 1 THEN 'Pending' ELSE 'Invoice Generated'
END
) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR DATE_FORMAT(
    shopify_order_created_at,
    '%m-%d-%Y'
) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR(
    CASE WHEN is_paused = 0 THEN 'Running' ELSE 'Paused'
END
) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR DATE_FORMAT(
    shopify_recurring_date,
    '%m-%d-%Y'
) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' AND DATE_FORMAT(
    shopify_order_created_at,
    '%Y-%m-%d'
) BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY
    `id`
HAVING
    parent_id = 0 AND shopify_order_type = 1
ORDER BY
    `id`
DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Is this query optimized? Is this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE o.parent_id = orders.id AS recurring_order_count` line most expensive in terms of query execution speed? Is there anything I should take care to improve the query speed here? Please advise.

Comment: Are you facing any specific problems?

Comment: Although lengthy this seems like a simple query (apart from the sub-query). Most optimizations will have to do with choosing the correct indexes. What are your indexes?

Comment: `LIKE '%GERALD8314%'` is not SARGable, there's not much to improve performance-wise. All the `OR`'s in the `WHERE` is usually a performance killer too, you may be able to get better performance if you use `UNION`s

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Indexes are - parent_id, is_paused , is_paused , coupon_id , is_paid , is_invoice_generated , shopify_order_type

Comment: @HoneyBadger Will try UNION as you suggested.

Comment: You `order by` the `id` column. That would be a nice new index for your `UNION` query.

Comment: you can also try to move the subquesry to the `FROM` section with a `LEFT JOIN`, be sure to have an index on id AND on parent_id

Comment: @MtwStark Will do as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` and `LIKE` with leading wildcard are terrible for performance.  Consider having a `FULLTEXT` index across the relevant columns.  If it is practical, it will be immensely faster.

```
    WHERE  coupon_code LIKE '%GERALD8314%'
      OR  shopify_order_id LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR( CASE WHEN is_paid = 0 THEN 'No' WHEN is_paid = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'Rejected' END ) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR( CASE WHEN is_invoice_generated = 1 THEN 'Pending' ELSE 'Invoice Generated' END ) LIKE '%GERALD8314%'
      OR  DATE_FORMAT( shopify_order_created_at, '%m-%d-%Y' ) LIKE '%GERALD8314%' OR( CASE WHEN is_paused = 0 THEN 'Running' ELSE 'Paused' END ) LIKE '%GERALD8314%'
      OR  DATE_FORMAT( shopify_recurring_date, '%m-%d-%Y' ) LIKE '%GERALD8314%'
      AND  DATE_FORMAT( shopify_order_created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Also, there may be surprises in the results.  Note that you have

```
a OR b OR c AND d
```

which is the same as

```
a OR b OR (c AND d)
```

I suspect you wanted

```
(a OR b OR c) AND d
```

I think the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary.  And the `HAVING` clauses can be merged into the `WHERE`.

```
    GROUP BY  `id`
    HAVING  parent_id = 0
      AND  shopify_order_type = 1
    ORDER BY  `id` DESC
```

This has multiple issues:

```
DATE_FORMAT( shopify_order_created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

`BETWEEN` is "inclusive".  The way you have written the query, it will include the entire ending *day*.  This may not be what you wanted.

Assuming the variable is a DATE or DATETIME, it can be simplified to

```
shopify_order_created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

There may be more tips; fix these then come back for more.